# Save added rows in DataGridView to database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to save a new added row in a `DataGridView` to a database. I can't understand which method to call - either `gridview1_UserAddedRow` or `gridview1_RowsAdded` (what if it's just one row?).. So far, I've seen that `gridview1_RowsAdded` executes every time when the form loads.

The `DataGridView` is bound using a `BindingList`.

This is how the `gridview1_UserAddedRow` looks like:

```
private void dataGridView1_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int lastRow = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2;
    DataGridViewRow newRow = dataGridView1.Rows[lastRow];
    bindinglist.Add(new MyTestClass{ ScheduleId = scheduleId, Name = Convert.ToString(newRow.Cells["Name"].Value),
    Value = Convert.ToString(newRow.Cells["Value"].Value), TestId = testId});
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and nothing is inserted. Actually, I think this event is called when a new row is clicked. How else can I insert the newly created row in the database?

Comment: Your last row index is calculated wrong. You need to minus one: `dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not updating anything to the database as there is no code to update it.

You need to execute a query to update those new values. You could try using `Commands`: 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984369(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984369%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Or change the list to a `DataTable`, which allows you to update the values 'automatically' (a bit harder): [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away form **databinding**, but if you can't, you can try this:

```
// Create a new row
DataRow dr = YourDataSet.Vendors.NewRow();  // Change 'Vendors' with your database table's name

// Add some data to your new row    
dr[0] = 124;

// Insert the previous row
YourDataSet.Vendors.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 1);  // Change the 1 to your index where you want to insert the data.
```